# How to make a header image respond to changes in screen size?

Tags: javascript, html, css

The header image on the website I am working on responds to changes in screen size when going down in size (smaller) however, does not respond when going to a bigger screen size.

Link: `Removed`

If you go to a smaller screen size, refresh, and then expand the window, you will see the problem. The bottom of the image becomes cut off with a black space filling the area.

HTML:

```
<div class="intro">
    <div class="intro-inner">
        <div class="intro-bg">
            <div class="intro-bg-item"> 
                <div class="intro-bg-item-image" style="background-image: url(css/images/pb/home-banner.jpg)"></div><!-- /.intro-bg-item-image -->
            </div><!-- /.intro-bg-item -->
            
        </div><!-- /.intro-bg -->
    </div><!-- /.intro-inner -->
</div><!-- /.intro -->
```

CSS:

```
.intro { position: relative; text-align: center; color: #fff; background-color: #000; max-height: 100vh; overflow: hidden;}
.intro-inner { position: absolute; bottom: 0; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; }
.intro:after { content: ''; display: block; padding-top: 45%; }
.intro:before { content: ''; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, .5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 40%); z-index: 3; }

.intro-bg { position: fixed !important; height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: Do you know about the size-units vw and vh? for example 100vw and 100vh? It seems to me that your background is resized by script which leads to an ugly effect while resizing (you see the black background flicker through the image).

Comment: @Psi there is the carouFredSel script running which I believe is affecting the size. Have you ever used this?

Comment: No, didn't hear about it yet

Comment: What Browser are you using? It seems to work fine for me in Chrome.

Comment: I just altered it and now it works fine for chrome, however when I test it on my iphone on Safari it doesn't work. @Staveven

Comment: @Psi do you think that if I included a script to resize the image when the screen is resized it would fix the problem?

Comment: Not at all. I suggest to rely on only css to resize the image and avoid scripts that mess around with the image size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem persisted when viewing the website from a mobile device only. A less than ideal solution I came up with was to set the height of the image to be the WIDTH of the screen when on any screen size smaller than a laptop.

CSS:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation: landscape) {
  .intro-bg {
    height: 100vw !important;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using bootstrap, try to use the class "img-responsive" for the logo 
and adjust the logo width using media queries for each screen size